# Program not waiting until button clicked c# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

This code should wait until I click the button but it's continuing if condition without any button click. Why is that?

```
TaskCompletionSource<bool> _tcs;
```

```
public async Task gCaptcha()
{
    string s = webBrowser1.DocumentText;

    if (s.Contains(captchaPageTxt.Text))
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(captchaPageTxt.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(new Form() { TopMost = true }, "please solve the captcha you have " + captchaSolveWaitTime.Text + " " +"seconds");

          _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
             await _tcs.Task // Here I want to wait until button3 clicked or checkbox1.checked. Then it need to continue with if condition etc.
        if (captchaCompleted.Checked)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

```
void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _tcs.SetResult(false);
}
```

Comment: if you breakpoint this line `if (captchaCompleted.Checked)` does it get hit?

Comment: forgot about that if condition, the code "await _tcs.Task"  should wait until I click a button. Then only it need execute if condition.

Comment: You are completely misunderstanding `await`. It does the absolute opposite of what you are expecting; it doesn’t block, it returns inmediately and marks the rest of the method as a continuation that will be executed once the task finishes.

Comment: Oh I will look in it. However how I can achieve what I want. I want to wait the program until I click a button or checked the checkbox to proceed.

Comment: If you want to block the UI until the user performs a certain task then use the normal options every UI uses: disable all controls except the one the user is supposed to interact with or show a modal dialog (`ShowDialog()`) with whatever task the user is supposed to perform.

Comment: @InBetween don't want to block the UI because the method gCaptcha called with in a for loop. Once user completed the captcha, user will click the button captcha completed so that program can proceed further. I can run a while loop but it takes cpu usage. If we don't make to wait the program until button clicked user ended up with continuous looping for next captcha without filling the previous one.

Comment: I fail to see the issue. If you are waiting for a user to click button then why do you need to block at all? Simply wait for the button click event. If you don't want the user messing around with no other control then disable them until user finishes whatever needs doing. Now, while you wait, if the application needs to process work then await that task, not the button click.